# Convert database entity to list in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Visual Studio project where I have imported my table using database entity.

My database connection is named `MyDBEntities` and my table name is `Full`.

So my view of my table `Full` is:

```
private MyDBEntities db = new MyDBEntities();

public ActionResult Index()
{
   return view(db.Full)
}
```

This works fine.

My model name is `FULL` and has these properties:

```
Int id, string Firstname, string Lastname
```

I need to put my database data into a list instead, how can I convert this?

```
List<Full> myList = ......
```

Comment: `db.Full.ToList()`? That pulls ALL records into memory - use `Where` to limit the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Linq convert entities to list

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return view(db.Full.ToList())
}
```

Comment: You need to explain your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
var items = db.Full.Select(f => new Models.Full()
{
    Id = f.Id,
    FirstName = f.FirstName,
    LastName = f.LastName
});

return View(items);
```

Will cast the `Full` entities as `Full` models; `items` is going to be `IEnumerable<Models.Full>`.  You don't really want a list because that will load everything into memory instead of enumerating one row at a time.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to have separated models for DB and web traffic, but your suggestion highlights the pitfalls of ToList.  Good stuff.